# Simple Annuities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

To finance the purchase of a car, Wendy agrees to pay $\$400$ at the end of each month for 4 years. The interest rate is j12 = 15%.

Assuming Wendy has missed no payments, what single payment at the end of 2 years would completely discharge her of her indebtedness?

$R = \$400$

$i = 0.15/12 = 0.0125$

$n = (4 \cdot 12)-(2 \cdot 12) = 24$

I've used the Discounted Value formula: $R\cdot [1-(1 + i)^{-n}]/i$

$400 \cdot [1-(1.0125)^{-24}]/0.0125 = 8249.693805$

But, this is not the right answer. Please help me figure out the right answer.

Comment: what is 'j12' in line 2, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: That's J subscript 12, sorry about that. It's the nominal interest rate compounded monthly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first calculate the future value at $t=24$ (months) of the first $23$ payements. This is

$$400\cdot \frac{1.0125^{23}-1}{0.0125}\cdot 1.0125=10,715.23$$

Then calculating the value at $t=24$ (months) of the $48$ payments.

$$\underbrace{400\cdot \frac{1.0125^{48}-1}{0.0125}}_{\texttt{Value of 48 payments at t=48}}\cdot \underbrace{\frac1{1.0125^{24}}}_{\texttt{Dicounting 24 months}}=19,364.93$$

The difference is the final payment which Wendy has to make.